# Stratified sampling ratio with srswor

Tags: variance, sampling, survey, stratification, efficiency

The variable X under study have rectangular distribution with  interval (a,  a+ d ) the interval is divided into k equal subintervals which form k equal  strata of equals sizes . From each stratum simple random sample of n/ k units is drawn . Let V1 and V2 be the variance in estimator of population mean based on stratified and  simple random sampling of size n .

**prove that  V1/V2 = 1/K²**

My attempt

V2 = Var($\ y_R $ ) = $\ ( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{\ k^2} ) \ S^2 $

As it is given in the question that total k stratum are of k subsamples in each of total population should be $\ k^2 $

V1 = Var($\ y_st $ ) = $\ ( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{\ k^2} ) \sum_{i= 0 }^{k} \ p_i \ S_i^2 $

So v1/v2 = $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\ k} \ S_i^2 }{k \ S^2} $

Is this correct approach ??

Please  help if you know how to solve

Comment: The sum in the definition of $V_1$ should be from 1 to $k$, not $0$ to $k^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio of the variances depends on the ratio of the within-stratum variances of $X$  to the overall variance of $X$.  In this case, the stratum-specific variance for an interval of length $k$ is proportional to $1/k^2$ (specifically, it's $(b-a)/12k^2$)

Comment: hey , I have tried to use your hint ans solve please review my answer .